# How to pass NSTimeInterval object to detachNewThreadSelector withObject parameter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsthread, nstimeinterval

I'm still new to Objective C syntax, so I might be overcomplicating this, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass an NSTimeInterval to a thread.

I want to initiate a thread that sleeps for x seconds parameter sent from main thread as follows:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(StartServerSynchThread) toTarget:self withObject:5];

- (void) StartServerSynchThread:(NSTimeInterval *)sleepSecondsInterval {

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:sleepSecondsInterval];

}
```

But the compiler keeps giving me a syntax error. I'm not sure exactly how it should be done. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This is almost exactly the same as @Georg's answer, but using the proper types. :)

If you box the NSTimeInterval into an `NSNumber` (a subclass of `NSValue`), you can pass that in instead:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startServerSynchThread:) 
                         toTarget:self 
                       withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myTimeInterval]];

- (void) startServerSynchThread:(NSNumber *)interval {
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:[interval doubleValue]];
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I like this solution better as it is more clear to what the method's arguments do. Also the run time error got fixed with the colon (:) after the method name "@selector(startServerSynchThread:".  Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 2):

The `object` parameter has `id` type, which means only class-type objects can be passed. Integers, like the `5` you are trying to pass, as well as `NSTimeInterval` (actually just a `typedef` for `double`), are fundamental types, not class-types.

You can use `NSNumber` as a wrapper or pass a `NSDate` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but the NSDate option seems a lot like a hack to me. Would you be kind enough to post the NSValue solution?

Also when I tried running the above code, I got a run time error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** -[MainScreenController StartServerSynchThread])'

Comment: @Yousef you forgot the `:` at the end of the method name.